# How to get the $A''$ point of the axial simmetry

Tags: geometry

I have this statement:

> To the point A of coordinates $(3, -3)$ a rotation of 90 ° with respect
> to point B of coordinates $(1,1)$, obtaining point A '. Then, at that
> point an axial symmetry is applied with respect to the line that
> passes through point A and the origin of the system. The coordinates
> of this new point are:
>
> A) (-3,-5)
>
> B) (-5,-3)
>
> C) (-1,3)
>
> D) (3,1)
>
> E) (3,3)

My current development is:

The rotation of point $A(3, -3)$ with an $\angle 90$ get an $A'$ of $(5,3)$. I get this result using translation and rotation. My problem is that i can't do the axial simmetry. I have only been taught that there is a symmetric with respect to the y-axis, (-x, y) and the x-axis (x, -y), but I do not know how to do it when the line is different, how should I do it?

So basically, my problem is:

**How can I find the coordinates of the symmetric point in an axial symmetry where the line is not the axis of the ordinates nor is the axis abscissa?(and with the data that they give me in the problem)**

Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:**

The key idea is that the line $OA$ is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $A'A''$.

Let $A''$ be represented by $(x,y)$.

The midpoint of the line segment $A'A''$ must be on the line $OA$, so that gives you one equation involving the unknowns $x,y$.

Also, the line $A'A''$ is perpendicular to the line $OA$, hence the product of the slopes is $-1$, which gives you a second equation involving the unknowns $x,y$.

Two equations, two unknowns.

Solve the system for $x,y$.